# How to iterate to find days? in smth["smth"]["1.555"]["2022-04-05T08:34:39+02:00"]

Tags: python, loops, csv

im trying to iterate this and cant figureout how. Theres .csv file.

QUESTION: so i finds LOW_num's data[0], and got to get TOP_num for TOP_num's data[0] < LOW_num's data[0] What the formula could be? The example:

```
for line in file: 
    data = line.split(sep)
```

A line looks like this:

```
2022-04-05T08:34:39+02:00, 1.2024, 1.2024, 1.2024, 1.2024, 1.2185, 1.2059028833000065, 1.2024784243912705, 1.2004400559932131, 1.198116316019428
```

So data[0] means Column A, data[1] is Column B, data[2] is Column C, (...)

```
memory["high"] = {}
memory["low"] = {}
    
for line in file: 
   data = line.split(sep)
       if data[5] < data[9]:
           memory["high"][float(data[2])] = str(data[0])
           memory["low"][float(data[3])] = str(data[0])
           # those are collecing data[2] and data[3] only between events when 
           # values changes from column F > J, to F < J, in that .csv file
```

then in the same "for line in file:", but different if:

```
    
LOW_num = min(memory["low"]) # it gets lowest number of all collected data[3] (Column D)
TOP_num = max(memory["high"]) # it gets biggest number of all collected  data[2] (Column C) 
#so TOP_num is for example: "1.555"
#but that TOP_num got day, month, and year attached to it as well: 
#ex: memory["high"]["1.555"]["2022-04-05T08:34:39+02:00"]
        
TOP_data0 = str(memory["high"][TOP_num])
LOW_data0 = str(memory["low"][LOW_num])
```

i tried some things but, cant get it righ, example:

```
for i in memory["high"][i][j]:
    if memory["high"][i][memory["high"][TOP_num][TOP_data0] < memory["low"][LOW_num]LOW_data0]:
       print(memory["high"][i][TOP_num])
```

The .csv file represents some coin's price data ex: ADAUSDT frome exchange,
(time, open, high, low, close, somthing, somthing, somthing, somthing, somthing)
I finds Lowest price of given time period (Low_num), starting from some start price earlier.
And must find the biggest price between those start point and Low_num point.
That biggets price is the Stop loss numer had to be set, in order to achive the Lowest point for this example, it was a short.

Comment: dont minus me, i m realy exhausted by many things and don't know where to get assistance, im willing to make tips for small helps in python, anyone can point me out how to do a good iteration, or hwere to search m greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

figured out!

```
memory["SL"] = {}
for number in memory["high"]:
    if number > LOW_num: # so its only numbers higher than Lowest obviously
        x = number
        if memory["high"][x] < LOW_data0: # and among them, with date only earlier than LOW_date0
            memory["SL"][x] = str(memory["high"][x]) # and saving it to new memory set for later max() or min() upon it
```

Wow python can compare dates!